# Panning/Zooming of Newly added points to d3.js Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

There are 2 set of arrays, the initial dataset is `data` and the newer dataset is `data2`. After adding `data` to the plot, panning and zooming works. I've created a `Chart` class for handling d3.js plots.

However after updating the plot with the array `data2` using `chart.update(chart.data2)`, only the points from `data` pans and zooms, the points from `data2` remains stationary. Is there an error in the code for `chart.update()`?

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/kzQ6K/

**chart.update()**

```
/**
 * Update Chart with new Data
 */
 this.update = function(newData) {
    uniqueNewData = _.difference(newData, this.data);
    this.data = _.union(this.data, uniqueNewData);

    // Update axes
    var yMin = d3.min(this.data.map( function(d) {return d.score;} ));
    var yMax = d3.max(this.data.map( function(d) {return d.score;} ));
    var xMin = d3.min(this.data.map( function(d) {return d.timestamp;} ));
    var xMax = d3.max(this.data.map( function(d) {return d.timestamp;} ));
    y.domain([yMin, yMax]);
    x.domain([xMin, xMax]);

    // Draw rects
    var svg = d3.select(this.div + ' svg');
    var rects = svg.selectAll('rect.data')
                            .data(this.data, function(d) { return d.timestamp || d3.select(this).attr('timestamp'); });
    rects
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .classed('data', true);

    rects
        .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.timestamp); })
        .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.score); })
        .attr('timestamp', function(d) { return d.timestamp; })
        .attr('width', 4)
        .attr('height', 10)
        .attr('fill', 'red')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')');

    svg.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
    svg.select('.y.axis').call(yAxis);


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `zoomed` function is not defined as a class member, and uses the variables `data`, `x`, `y`, etc. from its closure. These variables are not updated when the `zoomed` function is called.

Though this way of encapsulating the Charts may work out, the most standard way of doing it is by creating [`d3`*-esque* functions](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/).

Comment: `d3.event` is also `null` inside `Chart.zoomed` when it's called.

Comment: @Nyxynyx Where/how are you using `d3.event`? And I am assuming that you have redefined `zoomed` to be a class function? Could you please post a link to the updated code?

Comment: In jsfiddle.net/kNWGT/, if you pan/zoom the chart before clicking on the button to add new rects, then move the pan/zoom the chart again, you will see that 3 of the blue rects with the same data point as the initial 3 red rects do not line up when they should be identical datapoints...